# Почему я получил ограничение на код в google collab?

Tags: нейронные-сети, google-colaboratory

Я использую вот этот [блокнот](https://colab.research.google.com/github/TheLastBen/fast-stable-diffusion/blob/main/fast_stable_diffusion_AUTOMATIC1111.ipynb#scrollTo=PjzwxTkPSPHf&uniqifier=1)
Для быстрого запуска stable diffusion

Но с недавних пор при запуске
Install/Update AUTOMATIC1111 repo
Я получаю следующее предупреждение

> Предупреждение Вероятно, вы выполняете недопустимый код. Это может
> привести к удалению среды выполнения без предупреждения. Сервис Colab
> предназначен в первую очередь для интерактивных вычислений в
> блокнотах. Его нельзя использовать для некоторых задач, когда код
> выполняется без вычислительных единиц, как описано в разделе часто
> задаваемых вопросов.

Может кто сказать почему я получаю это предупреждение. Или сказать получаете ли вы его после запуска AUTOMATIC1111.
Я читал Seems too good to be true. What are the limitations?
Но какое отношение это имеет ко мне не понимаю.

Comment: Вы используете платную услугу? google collab [не любит использование webui в бесплатном плане](https://twitter.com/thechrisperry/status/1649189902079381505). И даже [рвет сессию если детектит](https://github.com/camenduru/stable-diffusion-webui-colab/issues/405),